# Can I use a Web ApiController to fetch a SelectList for a Html.DropDownList?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

Maybe I am missing the point, but I would like to retrieve some data for a dropdownlist in a MVC view from a  Web API Controller.

I thought to simply build something like this:

The API controller:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ListController : ApiController
{
    public IEnumerable<Foo> GetFoos()
    {
        return new List<Foo>( new[]
            {
                new Foo()
                {
                    Id = 1,
                    Name = "Foo 1"
                },
                new Foo()
                {
                    Id = 3,
                    Name = "Foo 3"
                }
            });
    }
}
```

So, in my view I am trying to use the Html extension helper like this:

```
@Html.DropDownList("FooId", new SelectList(Html.Action("GetFoos","api/List")))
```

Well, obviously, this gives me the error:

> The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList.SelectList(System.Collections.IEnumerable)' has some invalid arguments

But I can't seem to find a appropriate way to do this.

Is it possible? Or would I need to make an AJAX call with JQuery?

(ps. I am aware of the performance impact when dealing with a view to server call. It just would make my life a bit easier for now)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd recommend you to use Select2.js (http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/). It is highly configurable, has ability to fetch data from remote source and also allows you to format pretty much everything regarding the appearance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Html.DropDownList` is meant to work with the ViewModel, it will not retrieve the service request. To do this, you have to call your service from the client side via an ajax request, yes.

Usually you simply pass in the Model to your view and construct the dropdown list on the server side.

Comment: I see, well since I have a lot of dropdownlists all over the place I think I will build my own extension method. Otherwise I am constantly filling my view model with lists or building them with jquery, over and over again.

Comment: Or just use one of the 1000s of jquery plugins which gives you all this functionality

Comment: Since you seem to have a lot of experience with this: which plugin would you recommend?

Comment: Usually I create a special place in my application for all of those List of Values (I like to call them LOVs), so, everyone one that needs to fill a combo, just need to ask for the specific LOV you need for each combo. This way, you would have some sort of combo data source repository ;)

Comment: http://demos.kendoui.com/web/dropdownlist/remotedatasource.html for example. But you could also create an editortemplate for your drowdowns within your mvc view folders and simply use it for a custom model which describes the service call, this would be a pretty elegant way. Within the template you have the ajax call etc defined only once and in your views you can use `@Html.EditorFor()`